# View image from FTP site in browser rather than download

Tags: google-chrome

I used to be able to open PNG images from an FTP server in my browser.  However, after updating to the newest version of Chrome they always download or open in a separate application.

Is there a way to get Chrome to have the same behavior as before where it allowed me to view images in the browser directly when they are hosted on FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, not without an extension (maybe not even with one).

This is the result of [this chrome task](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6199005675520000), implemented in chrome 72, whereby chrome removed the ability to render ftp URLs. You can see [the discussion with the reasons for this change](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/eopgOoY1QLs) (mainly, it's an attack surface the chrome developers don't want to invest in).

Note that this is just a step as chrome and firefox both intend to remove ftp support at some point.

Comment: Wow, that is frustrating.  I understand the reasoning and am glad they are avoiding a method of attack, but it breaks my workflow.  I guess I'll just have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've liked the versatility of Chrome, but now I'll have to use a separate app to access the ftp distribution sites. 
The nannies are annoying.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your post is a comment, not an answer.  As a new member, you are limited to posting answers and questions.  Later, when you've accumulated reputation (site points) you'll be able to post comments and upvote questions, comments and proposed answers you find useful. Please review site guidelines on [ask] and [answer].  Also, you will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the SuperUser [tour].  If you follow the norms of the SuperUser community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well. Enjoy!